# Как остановить таймер а потом снова запустить?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть функция которая выполняеться каждые 5 секунд. Как сделать чтобы при клике на кнопку интервал перезапускался сначала.

Пример: каждые 5 секунд выводиться alert(). Но ка только мы нажимаем на кнопку (например на 4 секунде) то мы заново ждем 5 секунд до нового алерта.

Пример фнкции вывода алерта:

```js
var f = function() {
    alert("Привет")  
    setTimeout(arguments.callee, 5000);
 }
 setTimeout(f, 5000);
```

Comment: никак, таймеры одноразовые, если его остановил - то только новый создавать

Comment: @Grundy, это нужно только `setInterval` юзать?

Comment: @Doofy, интервал тот же таймер: один и тот же таймер нельзя остановить, а потом запустить, можно только создать новый

Comment: `arguments.callee` лучше не использовать, лучше дать имя функции и вызывать по имени

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
function f() { console.log('выполнено'); }
document.querySelector('button').onclick = function() { timer.start(3000); };

timer = {
  start: function(time) {
    if(typeof(t) == 'undefined') {
      console.log('старт');
    } else {
      console.log('заново');
      clearTimeout(t);
    }
    
    t = setTimeout(function() {f();}, time);
  }
}
```

```html
<button>Запуск</button>
```